# Identifying Tenda F3 router burned SMD regulator with marking 297V0

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification, surface-mount, markings

My **Tenda F3** router was not powering on. When I checked its PCB, this regulator was burned. Its marking is "**297V0**". It is a **6 pin SOT-23 SMD** component.

I didn't find its details on the internet. Does anyone know its datasheet or model, etc?

**Update:**

I traced the PCB around this regulator. It seems to be a switching regulator. After tracing its pins I drew the following circuit diagram.

I estimate the 3.3V power output from pin 6 because on this wire a (model H25S16) SPI EEPROM IC's VCC pin is connected. According to the EEPROM IC, its VCC can be a maximum of 3.6V. So I estimated that the output on pin 6 of this unknown component would be 3.3V.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution:

---

I have solved the problem by myself. I just de-soldered that burned component and after tracing its pins I figured out that I can install the **LM2596** Buck Converter to step down the **9V to 3.3 volts**.
I soldered the LM2596 according to the following diagram and now the router is alive and working perfectly.

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, This was flagged by other site members as it doesn't answer your original question to identify that IC. However, it does solve the original *problem* :) If you edit your question to add a line, something like "Or what else could I do, if I cannot identify that IC?" then your answer would fit with the modified question. || Note that your original question had no info about your skill level. While repair questions of consumer equipment are not usually on-topic here, your reverse-engineering to identify the faulty IC's o/p voltage & your alternative solution, may help others in future.

Comment: As you can see [here](/help/self-answer), to accept your own answer you must wait 48 hours after you asked the question. So please consider coming back in a couple of days and "[accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" your answer (or another answer, if a better one has been added in the meantime).  That will effectively close the topic and show readers that you don't need further replies. It is still possible that you will get other answers in future (perhaps even an identification of that IC) so please be open to accepting another answer, even if you initially accept yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be a lt1616 I'm trying to repair a Hoo Too two band wireless router and have also a 6 pin regulator with similar pinout to yours and no info for this marking Code. Anyway lt1616 datasheet matches perfectly the used regulator.